# UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes: and viewWillAppear: order

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios11

a quick question for any of you who might have an idea:

I recently encounter a bug in on of my app, and that have raised a little question.

The bug was caused by a piece of code trying to access to an array not yet set.
The funny buisness here was that the same code worked absolutely fine on an iPad Air, and crashed on an iPad Pro.

Indeed, i was trying to access the array in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method of my controller, and the array was initialized in the `viewWillAppear:` method of the same controller.

In any device that i have tried, exepted on the iPad Pro, the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method was always called after the `viewWillAppear:`, but on the iPad Pro, it is the other way.

I easily fixed the issue, but i'm still wondering why the iPad Pro have a different cycle than the other. Anyone have a clue about that?

(I'm on Objective-C, iOS 11.0)

Answer (score 0):

Change the collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath method for conditions like following

`if (array has data || data is downloading) {
  show activity indicator
} else {
  show data 
}`

Reload collection view when data loads

Comment: Yeah, thanks, as i told in the post, i've already fixed it, the real question here is why the order is different in different devices.

Comment: Not sure about that sir. @JeanBagarre

Comment: Not sure about what @ahmed ?

Comment: About different view cycles

Comment: I tested it on multiples device, and on the simulator, that happened every time. But it's easy to try it yourself if you don't believe me